# Change Orientation in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My app will be launched in Landscape,only one view can change to Portrait, in which there is a button,I click this button to change the orientation to Portrait.
It performed as expected on iPad(iOS 8.4,Deployment target: 7.0),and I made an iPhone version,in which I just made some adjust on UI,and it runs on iPhone 6 Plus simulator(Base SDK: 9.1,Deployment target: 7.0),but the button for chagning orientation doesn't work. 
And I want to know how to implement this in iOS 9;
The Below is my code:

```
- (void)changeOrientation
{
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]  statusBarOrientation];


     if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){



    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber  numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

    if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {

        value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    }else {

        value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown];
    }

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ScreenToPortrait" object:nil];
}else{



    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    }else {
        value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    }


    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ScreenToLandscapeLeft" object:nil];
}

    [UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This works on iOS9

```
NSNumber *orientationValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue: orientationValue forKey:@"orientation"];
```

1. Go to `General` tab from app target, and enable all orientations.
2. For all view which support only landscape orientation implement `supportedInterfaceOrientations()` and return landscape orientation value.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Helpful image added]

seen or set tick on General setting.